# Annotations - a method is given a type as a generic argument. Annotate the return type that should be exacly the same as given in the argument

Tags: python, python-typing

Similar to a `classmethod`, there is a method that takes a generic type as the first argument (not an object of the type). I want to annotate its return type as precisely the same type that is given in the first argument.

```
ChildT= typing.TypeVar("ChildT")

def load_child(child_type: ChildT, child_name: str) -> ChildT:
    # ...
    return child_type()
```

In the code below, the `load_child` shall be annotated to return the `child_type` type.

```
test_frame = load_child(FrameType, "some_frame") # I want this to work
test_frame = load_child(FrameType(), "some_frame") # But, of course, only this works with the code above
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `type[ChildT]` for the parameter type. Otherwise, `load_child` expects an *instance* of `ChildT` as its first argument.

```
def load_child(child_type: type[ChildT], child_name: str) -> ChildT:
    # ...
    return child_type()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with most classes. But using it with `QFrame` from `PySide2.QtWidgets` makes it deduce `Any`.  Therefore I don't have a problem with annotations as I originally thought, but with the `PySide` type stubs perhaps. You seem like an experienced SO user. Should I edit the question or ask a different one?

Comment: Probably a new question. I'm not sure how `QFrame` could be accepted as a component of `ChildT` without the return value working as well.